# Epidemic model (Pure birth process)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a population of $N$ individuals, some of them infected. Contacts between any two members of the population are according to Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ per day. When contact occurs, it is equally likely between any of the pairs of the population. Upon contact between infected and an uninfected member, the uninfected becomes infected with probability $p=p(n,N), n=X(t) = $ #of infected members of the population at time t. Starting with one infected individual, show that the expected time until the entire population becomes infected is $ET = \dfrac{N-1} {\lambda}\sum _{n=1}^{N-1}\dfrac {1} {n} $ ~ $\dfrac{1} {\lambda}Nln$ $N$ For large $N$, where T is the time by which the entire population is infected.

I know I have to find $p$ and model $X(t)$ as a pure Birth process with $\lambda_{n} = \lambda p$, given $X(t) = n$, and let $T_{n}$ be the time between the nth and the $(n+1)$th infection, then $T_{n}$ is exponential ~ $\lambda_{n}$ and $T=T_{1} +...+T_{N-1}$.

I also figure the "birth" probability i.e. the probability that someone uninfected becomes infected in penchant on two people getting together, so I come up with $\dfrac{n(N-n)} {( \begin{matrix} N\\ 2\end{matrix})} $, where I am saying n=total infected, N=total population, and $(\begin{matrix} N\\ 2\end{matrix})$ are the number of ways 2 people can meet up.

Can someone please help me solve this one? I need at least the next couple of steps, or if I'm way off, please tell me where and how to fix it. Thanks!